# kendo ui dropdown list default value

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

how is it possible to set a default select on a dropddownlist with kendo ui and angular js ? I tried with k-value but it doesn't work. I use angular 1.5 and es6. I want to display a list of users and each user has an id. Thanks !

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list="vm.dpwnN1"
        class="col s5"
        id="idUtilisateurResponsableN1"
        name="idUtilisateurResponsableN1"
        k-options="vm.responsableN1Options"
        k-value="vm.utilisateur.id_utilisateur_responsable_n1"
        ng-model="vm.utilisateur.id_utilisateur_responsable_n1"
        >
</select>

this.responsableN1Options = {
      dataSource: {
        transport: {
          read: promise => {
            this.getDataForN1(promise);
          }
        }
      }, dataBound: () => {
        this.utilisateur.id_utilisateur_responsable_n1 = this.dpwnN1.value();
      },
      optionLabel: 'Choisissez votre responsable (N+1)',
      dataTextField: 'nom',
      dataValueField: 'id',
      template: '{{dataItem.nom}} {{dataItem.prenom}}',
      valueTemplate: 'Responsable (N+1) : {{dataItem.nom}} {{dataItem.prenom}}',
      animation: {
        close: {
          effects: 'fadeOut zoom:out',
          duration: 300
        },
        open: {
          effects: 'fadeIn zoom:in',
          duration: 300
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery , Add the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var dropdownList = $("#idUtilisateurResponsableN1").data("kendoDropDownList"); 
 dropdownList.select(0); // in this case first option will be default value.
})    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value of the DropDownList using the "value" configuration option:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-value

So in your case you would use:

```
   this.responsableN1Options = {
      dataSource: {
        transport: {
          read: promise => {
            this.getDataForN1(promise);
          }
        }
      }, dataBound: () => {
        this.utilisateur.id_utilisateur_responsable_n1 = this.dpwnN1.value();
      },
      optionLabel: 'Choisissez votre responsable (N+1)',
      dataTextField: 'nom',
      dataValueField: 'id',
      value: vm.utilisateur.id_utilisateur_responsable_n1,
      template: '{{dataItem.nom}} {{dataItem.prenom}}',
      valueTemplate: 'Responsable (N+1) : {{dataItem.nom}} {{dataItem.prenom}}',
      animation: {
        close: {
          effects: 'fadeOut zoom:out',
          duration: 300
        },
        open: {
          effects: 'fadeIn zoom:in',
          duration: 300
        }
      }
    };
```

Where I have inserted "value" after the "dataValueField" option.